# How to use print.css to make a select look like normal text

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, printing

I have a web page that display this:

[image]

The Html behind this is:

```
<label>Approved For Payment:</label>

    <select id="Invoice_ApprovedForPayment" class="dropdownapprovedforpayment" name="Invoice.ApprovedForPayment" lineid="299" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="null" selected="selected">Please Approve</option>
    <option value="true">Accepted</option>
    <option value="false">On Hold</option>
    </select>
```

Currently when this page is printed the Please Approve is coming out like shown. As in it prints it as a select dropdownlist. This makes sense however I was hoping that I could somehow get it so that when it prints it will look like it's a normal label, span etc? I was thinking this may be possible using print.css? Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way that I can think to accomplish this would be to create a span that is hidden in `screen.css` next to the select list and when you change the value in the select list, update the value of the span. In your `print.css` show the span and hide the select element

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Invoice_ApprovedForPayment").change(function() {
      $("#Invoice_ApprovedForPaymentSpan").val($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="Invoice_ApprovedForPayment" class="dropdownapprovedforpayment noprint" name="Invoice.ApprovedForPayment" lineid="299" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="null" selected="selected">Please Approve</option>
  <option value="true">Accepted</option>
  <option value="false">On Hold</option>
</select>
<span id="Invoice_ApprovedForPaymentSpan" class="noscreen"></span>
```

**CSS**

***print.css***

```
.noprint { display: none; }
.noscreen { display: inline; }
```

***screen.css***

```
.noprint { display: inline; }
.noscreen { display: none; }
```

Just make sure that the media for your print stylesheet is set to print

Comment: Cool, I think to make it work though instead of $("#Invoice_ApprovedForPaymentSpan").val($(this).val());
 I need $("#Invoice_ApprovedForPaymentSpan").text($(this).text());

Comment: ahh, good call. I was totally thinking of it as being an `input`

Answer (score 6):

```
appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Works well on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using jQuery, without having to manually add spans by all your selects.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('beforeprint', function(){
        $('select').each(function(){
            $(this).after($('<span class="select-print">' 
                + $(this).find('option:selected').text() + '</span>'));
        });
    });
    $(window).bind('afterprint', function(){
        $('.select-print').remove();
    });
})
</script>
<style>
@media print {
    select { display:none }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Print.css under the Content folder if you havent already
2. add this line to _Layout.cshtml `<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Print.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />`
3. add select { yourStyle } to Print.css replacing yourStyle with the style you want.

note, IE9 appears to ignore print media stylesheets, at least the print preview does.  this works fine in chrome.  haven't tested others.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery to add a `<ul>` block with `<li>` for each `<option>` after the `<select>` that is shown only when printing.

```
    // Build <ul> for our select
    var inputfield = "select.print_this_select";  // process one or more selects (use "select" for all)
    $(inputfield).addClass('printable-select');  // Hide select
    $(inputfield).each(function() {   // Add our <ul>
        var ul = $('<ul></ul>').addClass('print-select');  // only show it on print
        $(this).find("option").each(function() {
            text = $(this).text();
            if ('Please Approve' != text)   // Skip "instruction" option
                ul.append("<li>" + text + "</li>");
        });    
        $(this).after(ul);
    });
```

CSS:

```
/* Hide the original <select> and reveal our new <ul> */
@media print {
    .printable-select {
        display: none;
    }
}

.print-select {
    /* Hide our <ul> until needed */
    display: none;
    
    @media print {
        /* Reveal our <ul> on print */
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('select').each(function()
    {
        val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        $(this).prev().html(val);
    });
});
```