# DataTables print only selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with select inputs and a print button, while printing I am getting all the select option tag text. How do I print my table with only selected option visible?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To me, going deeper into modifying DOM (adding extra hidden `<span>` nodes, keeping their contents up to date and toggling visibility of those with original `<select>` nodes upon printing) rather than using actual DataTables data is the way of drifting far and away from DataTables API.

What I may suggest instead, is to customize printing window by [extending](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/customisation.html) default behavior of a <kbd>Print</kbd> button:

```
$('table').DataTable({
    ...
    buttons: [
        ...
        {
            extend: 'print',
            customize: function(win){
                /* prepare whatever printing page you like */
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

From within `customize` option callback you may grab your table's data into variable and cook up another `DataTable()` suitable for printing within print window (`win`).

By *suitable* for printing here I mean that you may strip off interactive elements (searchbar, buttons, paging controls, etc) and replace user-input elements, like `<select>` or `<input>` with their corresponding values. E.g. *printable* version settings may, thus, contain:

```
$('table').DataTable({
    ...
    dom: 't',
    paging: false,
    order: []
})
```

One thing you should bear in mind is that whenever user interacts with `<select>` elements within your original table, you **have to** commit those changes onto underpinning data (which you will use for printing later on), like:

```
$('table').on('change', 'tbody select', function(e){
    dataTable.cell($(this).closest('td')).data($(this).val());  
});
```

Complete **demo** of this approach you may find below (it fails to open printing window due to live snippet security policies, you may refer to this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/LYPLOZz) or clone both JS and HTML to your local environment).

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
 const dataTable = $('table').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bt',
  data: [{opt: '', val: 'valueA'}, {opt: '', val: 'valueB'}, {opt: '', val: 'valueC'}],
  columns: [{
    title: 'Options',
    data: 'opt',
    render: data => '<select>'+['','Option1','Option2','Option3'].reduce((options,option) => options+=`<option value="${option}" ${option == data ? 'selected' : ''}>${option}</option>`,'')+'</select>'
   }, {
    title: 'Value',
    data: 'val'
   }
  ],
  buttons: [{
   extend:'print',
   customize: function(win){
    const tableData = $('table').DataTable().data();
    $(win.document.body).html('<table></table>');
    $(win.document).ready(() => {
     $(win.document.body).find('table').DataTable({
      dom: 't',
      data: tableData,
      paging: 'false',
      order: [],
      columns: [
       {title: 'Options', data: 'opt'},
       {title: 'Value', data: 'val'}
      ]
     })
    })
   }
  }]
 });
 
 $('table').on('change', 'tbody select', function(e){
  dataTable.cell($(this).closest('td')).data($(this).val()); 
 });
})
```

```html
<!doctype html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" /><script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script> </head><body><table></table></body></html>
```

*p.s.* I couldn't suggest relevant code, since you didn't post any of yours, however, I guess the concept is sound clear, so you may easily deploy that in your project

Answer (score 0):

First thing first browser do not try to print select option and only print the selected option which means there is something wrong with your print CSS or you are not some using native functionality.

The post below provide a way to deal with your problem if you do not want to sort the above thing out.

[How to use print.css to make a select look like normal text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932524/how-to-use-print-css-to-make-a-select-look-like-normal-text)

In a Nut shell:

Step 1: make a span element next to select
Step 2: keep the span object updated in case of change in variable
Step 3: in your print css keep select hidden. Use @media print only
Step 4: in your screen css keep the span hidden. Use @media screen only

Enjoy and please read the original answer.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Method 1 :**

Try keeping the default value of select box to blank.

**Method 2 :**

You can keep a hidden `text-box` which is binded with `select-box` value and use media query to show and hide text box while printing.

```
@media print 
{
   input.hidden{display:block;}
   select.language-box{display:none;}
}
```

**Method 3 :**

Also there this event which might help

```
<body onbeforeprint="myFunction()">
```

Though the support for this event is not clear. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeprint.asp

*Hope that answers your question :)*